# Sum rows on basis of current and next row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an input in following format:
[image: Input Image]

I have to find the difference of the stop of current row and the start of next row, and if the difference is less than 25, i need to sum the values in [TimeDiff_Start_Stop]. If the difference is more than 25 i do not need to do the sum.

As in the above image, difference

between Stop of Row 1 and Start of Row 2 is 13,
between Stop of Row 2 and Start of Row 3 is 2, 
between Stop of Row 3 and Start of Row 4 is 1, 
between Stop of Row 4 and Start of Row 5 is 3, 
between Stop of Row 5 and Start of Row 6 is 8,
but the difference between Stop of Row 6 and Start of Row 7 is 37, 
therefore only [TimeDiff_Start_Stop] of first 6 rows is summed up, producing the row 1 in output.

Moving further difference between Stop of Row 7 and Start of Row 8 is 20, 
therefore [TimeDiff_Start_Stop] of row 7 and row 8 is summed up, producing the row 2 in output.

Required output

[image: Output Image]

How should i achieve this ?

Please find below scripts for input and output:

Input:

```
select 'Sample' as COL1,'1' AS COL2,1 as 'RN','2016-05-09 02:45:18.239669' AS Start,'2016-05-09 02:45:25.837316' as Stop,7 as TimeDiff_Start_Stop
union
select 'Sample' as COL1,'1' AS COL2,2 as 'RN','2016-05-09 02:45:38.809919' AS Start,'2016-05-09 02:46:59.856081' as Stop,81 as TimeDiff_Start_Stop
union
select 'Sample' as COL1,'1' AS COL2,3 as 'RN','2016-05-09 02:47:01.831128' AS Start,'2016-05-09 02:48:55.211807' as Stop,114 as TimeDiff_Start_Stop
union
select 'Sample' as COL1,'1' AS COL2,4 as 'RN','2016-05-09 02:48:56.305736' AS Start,'2016-05-09 02:50:06.107262' as Stop,70 as TimeDiff_Start_Stop
union
select 'Sample' as COL1,'1' AS COL2,5 as 'RN','2016-05-09 02:50:09.269354' AS Start,'2016-05-09 02:50:16.081159' as Stop,7 as TimeDiff_Start_Stop
union
select 'Sample' as COL1,'1' AS COL2,6 as 'RN','2016-05-09 02:50:24.819440' AS Start,'2016-05-09 02:51:04.736300' as Stop,40 as TimeDiff_Start_Stop
union
select 'Sample' as COL1,'1' AS COL2,7 as 'RN','2016-05-09 02:51:41.029165' AS Start,'2016-05-09 02:54:04.186215' as Stop,143 as TimeDiff_Start_Stop
union
select 'Sample' as COL1,'1' AS COL2,8 as 'RN','2016-05-09 02:54:24.537167' AS Start,'2016-05-09 02:55:26.926029' as Stop,62 as TimeDiff_Start_Stop
```

Output:

```
select 'Sample' as COL1,'1' AS COL2,'2016-05-09 02:45:18.239669' AS Start,'2016-05-09 02:51:04.736300' as Stop,319 as Time
union
select 'Sample' as COL1,'1' AS COL2,'2016-05-09 02:51:41.029165' AS Start,'2016-05-09 02:55:26.926029' as Stop,205 as Time
```

Comment: Always helps to add DDL and inserts for sample data instead of screenshots.

Comment: Thanks @MaxSzczurek . Updated the scripts.

Comment: LAG and LEAD are useful here

Comment: Thanks @Mihai. Will try with these.

Comment: @Mihai  In the input, we already have RN which can be used while creating self join on the input table, say InputTable T1 LEFT JOIN InputTable T2 ON T1.COL1 = T2.COL1 and T1.COL2 = T2.COL2 AND T1.RN = T2.RN + 1. This can be used instead of LEAD and LAG.
And with this, first row in output can be easily generates. 

The problem arises when we try to generate the second row.

Comment: Lead should be easier - to get the difference between the current row and next row in seconds, use this:
datediff(ss, stop, lead(start) over (order by rn))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are 2 different approaches - for this, I created a table @t and used your sample data to populate it - thanks for proving those. Here's the table definition:

```
declare @t table (col1 varchar(10), col2 int, rn int, start datetime2, stop datetime2, timediff_start_stop int)
insert into @t ... (from the OP)
```

Here's an approach using a CTE. First, it creates a CTE that just adds the diff (using LEAD to get the difference between current row stop/next row start) as a column.

Note the isnull statement in the CTE query gives a value of 26 to a null if there's no following row - this means the last row in the result set with get a value of 26 (> 25, so will match the criteria of a row that should be an end time in the result set).

```
;with tdiff (col1, col2, rn, start, stop, timediff_start_stop, diff, timediff)
as
(
select col1, col2, rn, start, stop, timediff_start_stop, isnull(datediff(ss, stop, lead(start) over (order by rn)), 26) as diff, datediff(ss, start, stop)
from @t
)
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.start, (select min(stop) from tdiff where stop > t1.start and diff > 25) as stop, 
    (select sum(timediff_start_stop) from tdiff where start >= t1.start and stop <= (select min(stop) from tdiff where stop > t1.start and diff > 25)) AS TIME
from tdiff t1
left join tdiff t2 on (t1.rn - 1) = t2.rn
where t1.rn = 1 or t2.diff > 25
```

Next, here's a completely different solution using cursors. Cursors are inefficient and not well suited to frequently-run tasks, but I find them easy to maintain and follow as a developer, and think it may be useful for some who need to run infrequent or one-time tasks that are suitable for cursors:

```
declare @outputtable table (start datetime, stop datetime)
declare @curstart datetime, @curstop datetime, @curdiff int
declare @outputstart datetime

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR   
select start, stop, datediff(ss, stop, LEAD(start) over (order by rn))
from @t
OPEN cur  

FETCH NEXT FROM cur   
INTO @curstart, @curstop, @curdiff 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN       
    if (@outputstart is null)
        set @outputstart = @curstart

    if (@curdiff > 25)
    begin
        insert into @outputtable values (@outputstart, @curstop)
        set @outputstart = null
    end

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur   
    INTO @curstart, @curstop, @curdiff
END   
CLOSE cur;  
DEALLOCATE cur;  

insert into @outputtable values (@outputstart, @curstop)

select * from @outputtable
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @MaxSzczurek. It worked. But i really want to do without using cursors. The actual data i have is in millions. Can we do it in some other way ? Using CTE or some other thing.

Comment: Yeah, working on a solution without a cursor now! Cursors are last resort, but sometimes useful in one-time/rare/infrequent processes because the code logic is easy to follow, IMO.

Comment: Yes. I agree. Meanwhile, i am trying to integrate datediff(ss, stop, LEAD(start) over (order by rn)) part in my code. This will probably remove the use of self join. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Max. This has got one more issue. We need to return the sum of all the values in Time column as well, while we are finding the min(EventStop) . 



    select t1.col1,t1.col2,t1.start, (select min(stop) from tdiff where stop > t1.start and diff > 25) as stop,sum(t1.TimeDiff_Start_Stop)
from tdiff t1
left join tdiff t2 on (t1.rn -1) = t2.rn
where t1.rn =1 or t2.diff > 25
group by t1.col1,t1.col2,t1.start  

When trying to achieve this, we only get the time for first row corresponding to the start only.

Comment: @Logical did this answer your question?

Comment: Yes. It really helped. Thanks a lot.